# Implementing Database Listener

Tags: java, database, swing, postgresql, listener

I'm developing a Java desktop application with Swing as GUI. The app contains services that query from database every seconds to make the interface synced from database. We all know that with this approach, performance is the enemy.

What I want to achieve is that every changes made from database, altered thru psql (Postgres command-line) for example, my app should be notified to update the UI. In this way, performance may be optimized.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you done so far? When you say 'database' you say the data in you db or the structure of your db ?

Comment: Your requirements are very vague. Do you want to catch any changes, including those caused by external things like psql or are changes done through some central server application?

Comment: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/listennotify.html

Comment: @horse, that is absolutely awesome.  Excellent find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @a_horse_with_no_name points out, PostgreSQL supports asynchronous notification channels for just this purpose.

You should [create a trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html), probably in [plpgsql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html), on the table(s) you wish to monitor. This trigger [fires a `NOTIFY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html) when the table changes, optionally including the changed data its self.

The application [`LISTEN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html)s on the notification channel(s) and [processes any asynchronous notifications it receives](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/listennotify.html).

Note that it's valid to send an empty query, and you should do that instead of `SELECT 1`. e.g.:

```
stmt.execute("");
```

IIRC even that's optional if you're not using SSL, there's a way to poll purely client side. I don't remember what it is, though, so that's not real helpful.

You can determine exactly what changed by using a trigger-maintained change list table, or by using payloads on your notifications. Or you can simply re-read the whole table if it's small.

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks! Creating trigger under a specified table is a good thing in Postgres. I now realized that this can save lots of time in development and performance maybe. Querying every second silently causes flood in the connection pool. But technically, I still don't know if triggers have drawbacks. Maybe I'll just check if there's any.

Comment: @EriezeLagera A trigger that just sends a `NOTIFY` is pretty lightweight. It's a bit more expensive if you maintain a change history table, but still not drastic.